# Escaping with backslash or quoting in the shell?

Tags: python, shell

When starting a program via the command line using `os.system(program file_argument))` and where the argument is a file (which might have whitespace in it) what is the best way to send the argument to the other program?

I've looked at these options:

- Using `pipes.quote(file_name)` (or `shlex.quote(file_name)` for Python 3) which produces a string like this: `'/dir/file with white space'`
- Using `re.escape(file_name)` which produces string like this: `/dir/file\ with\ white\ space`

Are there differences between using these that might impact the program that is called? (Are there any other options?) Anything else i need to consider?

Comment: the best way is through `subprocess.call`. You can pass a list of arguments, and the quoting will be done automatically.

Comment: `re.escape` is for regex escaping. It does a completely different thing from what you need.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That's misleading. With `subprocess.call([...])` no quoting is *necessary* because no shell is involved; with `subprocess.call('...', shell=True)` you need quoting just like with `os.system()`. In general, you should always prefer the former (i.e. avoid the shell if you don't specifically need it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(['cat', 'file with space.txt'])
```

Using `os.system`, while simple to get started, breaks down when trying to do more complicated tasks.

I wish I had given up on `os.system` much earlier and just got familiar with `subprocess`. Well worth the time.